# Google AppEngine ENV variables from Google Cloud Build Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml, google-cloud-build

So I have a CloudBuild trigger that builds my `cloudbuild.yaml` file and this is all fine and dandy. I also use the gcloud builder to run docker commands to pass ENV variables to my `Dockerfile`. for example:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/swift:4.2'
  args: ['test']
  id: 'Running unit tests'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build','--build-arg', 'PROJECT=$PROJECT_ID','-t', 'us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA', '.']
  id: 'Building docker image'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA"]
  id: 'Pushing built image to registry'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy']
  id: 'Deploying to AppEngine'
timeout: 1800s # 30 minute timeout
```

As you can see I, I'm using the ENV variables that all GCP resources have by default.(`$PROJECT_ID` for example). And in the docker command I'm passing it as an argument so I can use the `ARG` command in the dockerfile:

```
ARG PROJECT
FROM gcr.io/${PROJECT}/swift:4.2 as builder
WORKDIR /App
#Other commands....
```

Now all of this works fine and I'm able to build my image etc. now I want to deploy to app engine in the final step.
Only problem is that I'm using the same Dockerfile to uses the `swift:4.2` base image that's only located in my GoogleContainerRegistry so I need the `$PROJECT_ID` for my project to pull that.

My question is: Is there any way to have AppEngine build environment pass arguments to the docker build that builds my image when deploying? I have an `app.yaml` file and I know there's an `env_variables:` property and I know I'd be able to use the docker `ARG` or `ENV` command (can't remember which one) to get my `$PROJECT_ID` inside my Dockerfile. But the only problem is AppEngine doesn't have that Property defined as far as I know. The only other thing I can think of is to `echo` the `$PROJECT_ID` from Cloud Builder step to the end of the `app.yaml` file. But if there's a cleaner approach I'd love to hear about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for my needs.

`gcloud app deploy` has a flag `image-url` that can specify an already built image rather than rebuilding the Dockerfile. So I went with this as my final `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
   args: ['app', 'deploy', '--image-url', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA']
```

Basically point to the image I just built and pushed to my container registry.